# Label direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tkz-euclide

Let's consider this diagram:
[image]

that was produced by the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=8, ymin=-3, ymax=5.5]
    \tkzClip

    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 4.5/5/A, 7/0/B}
    \tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}\tkzGetLength{rR} \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rR pt)

    \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](O){$O$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](C,A,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.8 cm](C,A,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,C,A){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.8 cm](O,C,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,A,B){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.8 cm](O,A,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](A,B,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.8 cm](A,B,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,B,C){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.8 cm](O,B,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](B,C,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.8 cm](B,C,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](C,O,B){\footnotesize$2\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.35cm](C,O,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.2](C,O,B){$\cdot$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.8,sloped](A,O,C){\footnotesize$2\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.35cm](A,O,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.18](A,O,C){$\cdot$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.2,sloped](B,O,A){\footnotesize$2\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.7cm](B,O,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](B,O,A){$\cdot$}

    \tkzDrawSegments(C,O B,O A,O)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

We see that all the labels are aligned along the angles bisectors (that is what the option 'sloped' does). Is it possible to align them perpendicularly to the bisector, but still with the center on the bisector (like the center alignment)? So I want the label "2\angle C" (and B) to be positioned as "2\angle A" now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new macro `\tkzLabelAngleX`for drawing the label rotated 90° as a modified copy of `\tkzLabelAngle` (I don't know if there is a simpler way).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

% New version: 2021-01-11.
% Works with tkz-euclide version 4.0
\makeatletter
\def\tkzLabelAngleX{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@LabelAngleX}{%
                                        \tkz@LabelAngleX[]}}
\def\tkz@LabelAngleX[#1](#2,#3,#4)#5{%
\begingroup 
  \pgfkeys{tkzlabelangle/.cd, dist = 1}
  \pgfqkeys{/tkzlabelangle}{#1}
  \ifx\tkzutil@empty\tkzlabelangle% no value so calc angle of bisector
    \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#2)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirOne}
    \tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#4)\tkzGetAngle{tkz@dirTwo}
    \tkzNormalizeAngle(\tkz@dirOne,\tkz@dirTwo)
    \edef\tkzlabelAngle{\fpeval{(\tkz@SecondAngle+\tkz@FirstAngle)/2}}
  \fi
  \path  (#3) --+(\tkzlabelAngle:\tkzlabeldist) node[label angle style,/tkzlabelangle/.cd,rotate=90,#1] {#5};
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 4.5/5/A, 7/0/B}
    \tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}\tkzGetLength{rR} \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rR)

    \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](O){$O$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](C,A,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.8](C,A,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,C,A){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.8](O,C,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,A,B){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.8](O,A,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](A,B,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.8](A,B,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,B,C){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.8](O,B,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](B,C,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.8](B,C,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](C,O,B){\footnotesize$2\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.35](C,O,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.2](C,O,B){$\cdot$}
    \tkzLabelAngleX[pos=-0.6, sloped](C,O,A){\footnotesize$2\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.35](A,O,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.18](A,O,C){$\cdot$}
    \tkzLabelAngleX[pos=1,sloped,rotate=-90](B,O,A){\footnotesize$2\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.7](B,O,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](B,O,A){$\cdot$}

    \tkzDrawSegments(C,O B,O A,O)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `rotate=-90` is to prevent the C label being upside down. The positions are also adapted to put them closer to the angles.

[image]

Comment: It was a great solution, unfortunately it doesn't work with the latest version of tkz-euclide. It seems \labeldist is not defined anymore.

Comment: @TheFourthMan  No the code compiles if you remove the "cm". See my answer

Comment: I have updated the definition of `\tkzLabelAngleX` and the example code to work with tkz-euclide version 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Now with tkz-euclide v4 you can delete `\usetkzobj{all}`, `\tkzInit` and `\tkzClip`. You need to remove `cm` in `size=0.8cm` and `pt` after `\rR pt`. `\tkzGetLength`gives a result in `cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 4.5/5/A, 7/0/B}
    \tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
    \tkzGetPoint{O}\tkzGetLength{rR}        

    \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rR)
    \tkzDrawSegments(C,O B,O A,O)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)

    \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](O){$O$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](C,A,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.8](C,A,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,C,A){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.8](O,C,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,A,B){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.8](O,A,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](A,B,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.8](A,B,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](O,B,C){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.8](O,B,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.7,sloped](B,C,O){\footnotesize$90^\circ-\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.8 cm](B,C,O)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](C,O,B){\footnotesize$2\angle A$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l,size=0.35](C,O,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.2](C,O,B){$\cdot$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.8,sloped](A,O,C){\footnotesize$2\angle B$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.35](A,O,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.18](A,O,C){$\cdot$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.2,sloped](B,O,A){\footnotesize$2\angle C$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=lll,size=0.7](B,O,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](B,O,A){$\cdot$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Alain! I appreciate your work so much — tikz-euklide is an excellent package!